# Why move constructor of member variable is not called?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, lvalue, move-constructor

Consider the following classes. If I implement the move constructor myself as follow, why bar member `b` is not moved but copied? But if I use the default move constructor, then `b` is moved. Why `b(rhs.b)` doesn't call `bar(bar&&)` ?

I use g++ 9.2.1 with --std=c++11.

```
class bar {
public:
    bar() { cout << "bar constructor" << endl; }
    bar(const bar& rhs) { cout << "bar copy constructor" << endl; }
    bar(bar&& rhs) { cout << "bar move constructor" << endl; }
};

class foo {
    bar b;
public:
    foo() { cout << "foo constructor" << endl; }
    foo(const foo& rhs) { cout << "foo copy constructor" << endl; }
    // foo(foo&& rhs) = default;
    foo(foo&& rhs) : b(rhs.b) { cout << "foo move constructor" << endl; } // my version
    //               ^^^^^^^^
};

foo f;
foo g = std::move(f);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why `b(rhs.b)` doesn't call `bar(bar&&)` ?

Because `rhs.b` is an *lvalue*, and *rvalue references* don't bind to *lvalues*. As a result – and because *lvalue references* do bind to *lvalues* – **the overload `bar(const bar&)`, i.e., the copy constructor, is selected** instead of `bar(bar&&)`.

In order to get the move constructor selected, you need to mark `rhs.b` as "available for moving" with (`<utility>`) [`std::move()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) when initializing `foo`'s `b` member:

```
foo(foo&& rhs): b(std::move(rhs.b)) { /* ... */ }
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

This is a cast that turns the expression `rhs.b` into an *xvalue*, i.e., an *rvalue*, which binds to an *rvalue reference*. So, the move constructor is selected this time.

> But if I use the default move constructor, then `b` is moved.

The default move constructor performs a member-wise move.